# c# - Reading a complex file into a comboBox

Tags: c#, database, file-io, combobox, file-read

So I tried some research, but I just don't know how to google this..

For example, I got a .db (works same as .txt for me) file, written like this:

```
DIRT: 3;
STONE: 6;
```

so far, i got a code that can put items in a comboBox like this:

```
DIRT,
STONE,
```

will put DIRT and STONE in the comboBox. This is the code I'm using for that:

```
        string[] lineOfContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dbfile);
        foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
        {
            string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
            comboBox1.Items.Add(tokens[0]);
        }
```

How do I expand this so it put e.g. DIRT and STONE in the combobox, and keep the rest (3) in variables (ints, like int varDIRT = 3)?
If you want, it doesn't have to be txt or db files.. i heard xml are config files too.

Comment: Try creating a class to hold that information.  Splitting on a comma doesn't make sense since in your sample data, you aren't showing any commas.  Did you mean: colon?

Comment: A `ComboBox` has two properties which you can use.  One is `ValueMember` and one is `DisplayMember`.  You can read your db file into a table with two columns, `element` and `value` or something, for example.  Then set the `ValueMember` to be `value` and `DisplayMember` to `element`.  Of course, you will also have to make sure to set the data source of the `ComboBox` to the table with your data in it.

Comment: @LarsTech In my previous DB file i had commas, thats why its still there. For the new one i ofcourse have to go with semicolons. This bings me to an idea: If i have the linesplit on double dot thingy, can i still read the rest of the line somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
            cmb.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines("filePath").Select(d => new
            {
                Name = d.Split(',').First(),
                Value = Convert.ToInt32(d.Split(',').Last().Replace(";",""))
            }).ToList();
            cmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cmb.ValueMember= "Value";
```

remember it will require to use `using System.Linq;`
if your want ot reference the selected value of the combobox you can use
`cmb.SelectedValue;`
`cmb.SelectedText;`

Comment: I get an error that  ...Forms.ComboBox doesn't contain a definition for 'DataMember' and no extension method 'DataMember'... so on. Same for Value.

Comment: The example data the OP posted isn't comma separated. You would want to use ':' for the split and remove the ';' before converting the value.

Comment: are you splitting on the correct `Delimiter` ? here is what his data looks like `DIRT: 3;`

Comment: I will try to fix the wrong split thing myself, but thanks, i think thats a ncie solution. Have my upvote!

Comment: I used coma because in his code he was using `line.Split(',')` So I was not sure which was which

Comment: @Patrick I tried that code with the first comma replace with ":" and second comma replaced with ";". When i open the ComboBox it shows me no aviable items?

Comment: You have to use ":" in both split

Answer (score 1):

I think you've really got two questions, so I'll try to answer them separately.

The first question is "How can I parse a file that looks like this...

```
DIRT: 3;
STONE: 6;
```

into names and integers?" You could remove all the whitespace and semicolons from each line, and then split on colon. A cleaner way, in my opinion, would be to use a regular expression:

```
// load your file
var fileLines = new[]
{
    "DIRT: 3;",
    "STONE: 6;"
};

// This regular expression will match anything that
// begins with some letters, then has a colon followed
// by optional whitespace ending in a number and a semicolon.
var regex = new Regex(@"(\w+):\s*([0-9])+;", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (var line in fileLines)
{
    // Puts the tokens into an array.
    // The zeroth token will be the entire matching string.
    // Further tokens will be the contents of the parentheses in the expression.
    var tokens = regex.Match(line).Groups;
    // This is the name from the line, i.e "DIRT" or "STONE"
    var name = tokens[1].Value;
    // This is the numerical value from the same line.
    var value = int.Parse(tokens[2].Value);
}
```

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, I encourage you to check them out; they make it very easy to format strings and pull out values. http://regexone.com/

The second question, "how do I store the value alongside the name?", I'm not sure I fully understand. If what you want to do is back each item with the numerical value specified in the file, the **dub stylee**'s advice is good for you. You'll need to place the *name* as the display member and *value* as the value member. However, since your data is not in a table, you'll have to put the data somewhere accessible so that the Properties you want to use can be named. I recommend a dictionary:

```
        // This is your ComboBox.
        var comboBox = new ComboBox();

        // load your file
        var fileLines = new[]
        {
            "DIRT: 3;",
            "STONE: 6;"
        };

        // This regular expression will match anything that
        // begins with some letters, then has a colon followed
        // by optional whitespace ending in a number and a semicolon.
        var regex = new Regex(@"(\w+):\s*([0-9])+;", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        // This does the same as the foreach loop did, but it puts the results into a dictionary.
        var dictionary = fileLines.Select(line => regex.Match(line).Groups)
            .ToDictionary(tokens => tokens[1].Value, tokens => int.Parse(tokens[2].Value));

        // When you enumerate a dictionary, you get the entries as KeyValuePair objects.
        foreach (var kvp in dictionary) comboBox.Items.Add(kvp);

        // DisplayMember and ValueMember need to be set to
        // the names of usable properties on the item type.
        // KeyValue pair has "Key" and "Value" properties.
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
        comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

In this version, I have used Linq to construct the dictionary. If you don't like the Linq syntax, you can use a loop instead:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var line in fileLines)
{
    var tokens = regex.Match(line).Groups;
    dictionary.Add(tokens[1].Value, int.Parse(tokens[2].Value));
}
```

Comment: Neat, but to the "first question", how do I read the rest of the file after the Split?

Comment: @devRicher The way I wrote it works line-by-line, so you'll still have to do ReadAllLines as you did originally to get the lines into the fileLines array in my example.

Comment: @devRicher If you want your file to contain other things that aren't in the DIRT:3; format, then you'll need to use the regex to test whether the line *is* a match. If it is then you can use the parsed tokens just as I am. If it isn't you'll do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use FileHelpers library. First define your data record.

```
[DelimitedRecord(":")]
public class Record
{
  public string Name;
  [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right,';')]
  public int Value;    
}
```

Then you read in your data like so:

```
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Record));
//Read from file
Record[] res = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt") as Record[];

// write to file
engine.WriteFile("FileOut.txt", res);
```